# Aligning general tabular columns width within multiple sections

Tags: tables, sectioning

I have several issues with the formatting of my `tabular` pages. I'm trying to write my CV with several `sections` (Personal data, Education, etc.) and in each one I have a `tabular` environment with two columns: the first for dates and/or general titles, the second for the correspondent description.

Ex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{subscript}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip}
\RequirePackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[big]{layaureo}              
\usepackage{titlesec}                   

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{1pt}{1pt}

\begin{document}
\section{Work Experience}
\begin{tabular}{r|p{0.8\textwidth}}
\underline{\emph{2018}} & Ph.D Student at the \textbf{University of Blabla}, Blabla, Earth \\\textsc{Sept 2013} & \emph{Prof. Einstein Lab - Dept. of Physics}\\ & \footnotesize{\textsf{The group of Prof. Einstein focuses on bla bla}.}} \\
\end{tabular}

\section{Skills}
\begin{tabular}{r|p{0.8\textwidth}}
\textsc{Computer Skills} & Data analysis softwares \textit{(Blablabla, Blablabla -- Blablabla, Matlab)} -- Extras \textit{(\textsc{GNU/Linux}, Blabla, blabla)}.\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

- The `|` separator between the columns is placed at different positions depending on the width of the words in the first column.

  - Ex: Obviously words as `Computer Skills` occupies more space than `2016`
- The length of the second column depends on the remaining space

  - The text on the second column will not be aligned to the other columns if the first column has different width

[image]

Maybe it is not possible at all but due to the fact that I have different lengths, I would like to unify the dimensions of my columns in an "automatic" way (that is to say without adding personal fixed parameters like `2,5cm` in the `tabular` environment settings).

I already tried using the `tabular*`, `tabularx` as well as `multirow` environment but without success. I'm surely  missing something due to my lack of experience.

So my summarizing question is:

How can I generalize the width of the columns in order to have the final dimension uniform all along different sections?

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!

Comment: it is far simpler to just use a fixed length `p{..}` especially for a CV which is presumably a one-off document and you don't need an automatic workflow. Otherwise you have to measure each entry and at the end of the document write the required length to the aux file so it is available on the next run to use in p{..}/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `eqparbox` package for this.

First load `array` and then define a new columen type `L`:

```
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\begin{lrbox{\csname#1box\endcsname}}r%
  <{\end{lrbox}\eqmakebox[#1][r]%
  {\unhcopy\csname#1box\endcsname\strut}}}
```

A specification `L{colname}` will then produce columns which capture their content in a box of name `colnamebox` and place them in an `\eqmakebox` named by `colname`.  The property of `\eqmakebox` is that all such boxes in the same sequence will be given the same width, possibly after running LaTeX a second time.  You need to declare the `colnamebox` with `\newsavebox`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[big]{layaureo}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{eqparbox,array}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\begin{lrbox}{\csname#1box\endcsname}}r%
  <{\end{lrbox}\eqmakebox[#1][r]{\unhcopy\csname#1box\endcsname\strut}}}
\newsavebox{\mylheadbox}
\newlength{\mylheadwd}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\mylheadwd}{%
  \@ifundefined{eqp@this@mylhead}{0pt}{\eqp@this@mylhead}}}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{1pt}{1pt}

\begin{document}

\section{Work Experience}
\begin{tabular}{L{mylhead}|p{0.9\textwidth-\mylheadwd}}
  \underline{\emph{2018}}
  &Ph.D Student at the \textbf{University of Blabla}, Blabla, Earth \\
  \textsc{Sept 2013}
  &\emph{Prof.\ Einstein Lab - Dept.\ of Physics}\\
  &\footnotesize\textsf{The group of Prof.\ Einstein focuses on bla bla}. \\
\end{tabular}

\section{Skills}
\begin{tabular}{L{mylhead}|p{0.9\textwidth-\mylheadwd}}
  \textsc{Computer Skills}
  &Data analysis softwares (\textit{Blablabla, Blablabla ---
    Blablabla, Matlab}) --- Extras (\textit{\textsc{GNU/Linux}, Blabla,
    blabla}).\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

In the above code, I have removed all unused packages for this particular example and tidied up the text commands within in the table.   Note (a) if you are using `hyperref` then it should be the last package loaded, (b) `\footnotesize` does not take an argument, (c) abbreviations need to be written `Prof.\`, (d) round brackets are best outside of italics.

The above code also shows one way to capture the size of the given `\eqmakebox[mlhead]`es by storing this in the `\mylheadwd`.  The first time the document is compiled the variable when this is captured from, namely `\eqp@this@mylhead`, is not defined, so I have added a test for this.  The correct value is only available at the start of the document body, so the code has been encapsulated in `\AtBeginDocument`.  I have used this mechanism to determine a width for the second column in the tables.  Bernard's suggestion of using `tabularx` is a more practical way to this, but is limited to use in tables.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Andrew, I'll try as soon as possible in my whole CV. Regarding your comment (c): what's the best between `Prof.\ Einstein` and `Prof.~Einstein`?

Comment: The first allows a line break after Prof., so the choice depends on whether you want to allow that or not.

Answer (score 2):

A variant I was fine-tuning while @Andrew Swann was posting on a similar idea.

Note I removed `xelatex` specific packages, as you loaded `inputenc`, `fontenc` and `babel`. Also, the option `usenames` for `xcolor` is useless, as it has been the default for quite a few years.

I'd suggest to use `tabularx`, `eqparbox` and `collcell` to define a new `R` column type, which puts the contents of each cell in an `eqmakebox`.  In addition, I propose to define a new coloured, thicker vertical rule, inserted between columns as `v`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{url,parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[big]{layaureo}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{tabularx, eqparbox, collcell}
\newcommand\myeqmakebox[1]{\eqmakebox[COL][r]{\scshape#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\myeqmakebox}r<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{v}{!{\color{CornflowerBlue}\vrule width 3pt}}%

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{1pt}{1pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}

\begin{document}

\section{Work Experience}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}R v X@{}}
\underline{\emph{2018}} & Ph.D Student at the \textbf{University of Blabla}, Blabla, Earth \\%
Sept 2013 & \emph{Prof. Einstein Lab - Dept. of Physics}\newline \footnotesize{\textsf{The group of Prof. Einstein focuses on bla bla}.}
\end{tabularx}

\section{Skills}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}RvX@{}}
Computer Skills & Data analysis softwares \textit{(Blablabla, Blablabla -- Blablabla, Matlab)} -- Extras \textit{(\textsc{GNU/Linux}, Blabla, blabla)}.
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Bernard, I tried to implement your method but I get `Paragraph ended before \collect@cell@arg was complete. \end{tabularx}` `Missing \endgroup inserted. \end{tabularx}` in the log box. But my code has the `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}RvX@{}}` and `\end{tabularx}` at the end of the section.. Moreover I can get the pdf apparently without any major error

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove a few packages in order for it to load and run on my computer.  BTW, loading both color and xcolor is redundant.

So long as you use a fixed length p{} and right justify the tabulars AND nothing sticks into the margins, the columns will be aligned.  All you really need is to calculate the maximum width for the parboxes.

Since one can usually  tell the longest entry by just looking, I started by measuring the width of that (Computer Skills).  Then I calculated the remaining space from `\textwidth` after removing the tabular overhead.  (If you want to indent the tabular, also subtract `\parindent`).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{subscript}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
%\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip}
%\RequirePackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[big]{layaureo}              
\usepackage{titlesec}        
\usepackage{showframe}% debugging tool

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{1pt}{1pt}

\newlength{\maxwidth}

\begin{document}
\settowidth{\maxwidth}{\textsc{Computer Skills}}%
\setlength{\maxwidth}{\dimexpr \textwidth-\maxwidth-4\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}%
\section{Work Experience}
\noindent\raggedleft
\begin{tabular}{r|p{\maxwidth}}
\underline{\emph{2018}} & Ph.D Student at the \textbf{University of Blabla}, Blabla, Earth \\\textsc{Sept 2013} & \emph{Prof. Einstein Lab - Dept. of Physics}\\ & \footnotesize{\textsf{The group of Prof. Einstein focuses on bla bla}.} \\
\end{tabular}

\section{Skills}
\noindent\raggedleft
\begin{tabular}{r|p{\maxwidth}}
\textsc{Computer Skills} & Data analysis softwares \textit{(Blablabla, Blablabla -- Blablabla, Matlab)} -- Extras \textit{(\textsc{GNU/Linux}, Blabla, blabla)}.\\ \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]